# How to mark all emails as read in Yahoo Mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

When I visit [Yahoo! Mail](https://mg.mail.yahoo.com/neo/launch) in a desktop web browser, and I am using the "full-featured" and "newest" Yahoo! Mail interface, I don't see a way to mark all emails in all folders as "read."

The only option that I see is to right-click each folder title and then click *"Mark as read."* However, if you have many folders, this option is not particularly quick.

On a whim, to see if I could at all decrease the total number of necessary clicks, I tried left-clicking each folder title while holding down the <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> key. But this method did not select more than one folder at once, as I had hoped.

Is there a way to mark **all** unread emails as read? Does a relevant keyboard shortcut exist?

Answer (score 8):

On the far right edge of the **inbox** folder heading there is an arrow you can click on and select "mark as read" from the options ("mark as read" or "clean inbox"). Doing this actually marks all emails in inbox and all sub-folders of inbox at once, not page by page if you use CTRL+K or other mark as read options[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the latest Yahoo email you need to click the box of the email you would like to set as "Unread" and then go to the "Actions" button, select "Mark as Unread" and then click the "Apply" button.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way! Click on Unread Messages, then scroll all the way to the bottom of the messages, click on the "Select All" box and then click "Mark as Read" or the letter K.  I'm doing this now, but I have so many that scrolling to the bottom is taking a while.
[image]